# You must call removeView() on the child's parent first 2

Tags: java, android

There is not any problem when i switch from page one to two or tow to one , everything works fine
but when i want to switch from the third page to the second one i just getting crash

All Fragment is

```
public class CHASHNI4 extends Fragment {

    private View LayoutScreen;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        LayoutScreen = inflater.inflate(R.layout.acp_chashni4, container, false);


        return LayoutScreen;
    }
}
```

PageAdapter.java

```
public class PageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private int numOfTabs;

    public PageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int numOfTabs){
        super(fm);
        this.numOfTabs = numOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new CHASHNI();
            case 1:
                return new CHASHNI2();
            case 2:
                return new CHASHNI3();
            case 3:
                return new CHASHNI4();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return numOfTabs;
    }
}
```

ssss

```
2019-10-30 14:56:23.909 661-661/com.zarringovar.zarrincenter E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.zarringovar.zarrincenter, PID: 661
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:5259)
```

Comment: why you are using setretaininstace here?

Comment: i used sample code

Answer (score 1):

Use `LayoutScreen = inflater.inflate(R.layout.acp_chashni4, null);` instead-of using `LayoutScreen = inflater.inflate(R.layout.acp_chashni4, container, false);`

Comment: I use tish code . 2019-10-30 16:34:08.224 1569-1569/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.zarringovar.zarrincenter, PID: 1569
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:5259)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5090)

Comment: i Used 4 Tab 
from 4 to 3 crashed